# How to display popup by clicking on "save and publish" button in Umbraco content page

Tags: javascript, c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I want popup to show up when I click on "save and publish" in umbraco admin content page. should anyone knows how do I do that or at least how to hijack javascript code into umbraco admin pages.

Comment: Would you consider using Umbraco events? Please have [a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878637/can-i-inject-a-client-side-behaviour-into-the-umbraco-7-back-office-using-angula), might help.

Comment: Thanks, but ApplicationEventHandler run on the backend (c#), I'm looking for client implementation, I can't run javascript code from there.

Comment: perhaps you could explain in a little more detail what you want to achieve and why?  You can use angularjs hijacking perhaps, or if you want to use the notifications functionality on submit you can do that utilising `ApplicationEventHandler` and the `NotificationsService` - https://our.umbraco.org/apidocs/ui/#/api/umbraco.services.notificationsService